# ambari-server log host not found error

Tags: ambari

when I used Ambari to register agent's hosts, there is always an error:

```
05 Jan 2016 08:43:14,118  INFO [pool-8-thread-1] BSHostStatusCollector:55 - Request directory /var/run/ambari-server/bootstrap/2
```

05 Jan 2016 08:43:14,118  INFO [pool-8-thread-1] BSHostStatusCollector:62 - HostList for polling on [node25.hadoop.com]
05 Jan 2016 08:43:24,307 ERROR [qtp-client-53] AbstractResourceProvider:279 - Caught AmbariException when creating a resource
org.apache.ambari.server.HostNotFoundException: Host not found, hostname=

and I don't know why.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Running into this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I resolved it by restarting Ambari Agents to make agents reconnect it to

Comment: Having the same problem. I guess there are no agents installed yet at this stage. My gut tells me it is something about the dns.